# Mac and non-focusable windows

Tags: c++, macos

I am looking for something similiar like WS_EX_NOACTIVATE on windows for mac tool windows. What this does is to simply prevent the tool window to be activated. I am actually working with Qt but a general hint would do equally well to put me into the right direction.

EDIT:
Qt seems to use the "kFloatingWindowClass" constant on mac..

thanks alot!
Alex

Comment: Are you looking for Palette windows?

Comment: I'm not sure as I've got no knowledge on what qt calls under the hood. Qt says that when you're specifying the Qt::Tool flag it should behave like a palette but on my osx here (10.6.8), those windows are kept focusable as usual..?